# Trying to get the Distance between a point and the mouse in JS canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I´ve got the center of the Point with centerX and centerY and I want to get the distance between this point and the mouse.

I am getting an error saying that clientX does not work.

```
function dist(event){
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

  var a = centerX - mouseX;
  var b = centerY - mouseY;

  var dist = Math.hypot(a, b);
  if(dist <= 50){
    alert("test");
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). *"I am getting an error saying that clientX does not work."* It's not clear what that means. Always quote the ***exact*** error message.

Comment: It would help people help you if you included a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder now we'll have to wait two weeks the time they digest all these links content ;-)

Comment: Please show how this method is being called, if it is part of an event listener then show how it has been added, if it is in HTML markup e.g `<canvas onmousemove="dist...` or something like that, then show it. We need to see what called this function so we can know what `event` is at that time. Note that you can already check by yourself by logging its value in the console: `console.log(event);` and check from there if it looks what you were expecting.

Comment: @Kaiido - LOL, seven **is** a bit much.